# python plotting overrides data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have lot of binary and ascii files in one folder. I am reading them using glob module. Doing processing of the binary data so that I can plot them. And finally, I am trying to plot simplified binary data in one subplot and normal ascii file in another subplot. The problem I am facing is that it can generate plots for the corresponding binary files. But for the ascii files it just simply override the previous files and always generates the same plot. Here is the simplied version of the code for an example-

```
import glob 
import numpy as np
from struct import unpack
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

chi = sorted(glob.glob('C:/Users/Desktop/bin/*.chi'))

for index,fh in enumerate(chi):
    data = np.genfromtxt(fh, dtype = float)
    x = [row[0] for row in data]
    y = [row[1] for row in data]

binary = sorted(glob.glob('C:/Users/Desktop/bin/*.bin'))

for count,FILE in enumerate(binary):
    F = open(FILE,'rb')
    B = unpack('f'*1023183, F.read(4*1023183))
    A = np.array(B).reshape(1043, 981)
    F.close()

    #a = something column 1   # some further processing
    #b =  something column 2  # and generates 1D data

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 8.0))

    ax1 =fig.add_subplot(211,axisbg='w')
    ax1.plot(a,b)

    ax2 =fig.add_subplot(212, axisbg ='w')
    ax2.plot(x,y)

    plt.show()
```

Can somebody please explain why the files are replacing each other during plotting only for one set of data where the other set is plotting correctly?

Answer (score 1):

the structures of the loops is not correct in your example, you must have the plot command inside the loop over the ascii file, else only the last one is plotted. This should work:

try it like this:

```
import glob 
import numpy as np
from struct import unpack
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 8.0))

chi = sorted(glob.glob('C:/Users/Desktop/bin/*.chi'))

for index,fh in enumerate(chi):
    data = np.genfromtxt(fh, dtype = float)
    x = [row[0] for row in data]
    y = [row[1] for row in data]

    ax1 =fig.add_subplot(211, axisbg ='w')
    ax1.plot(x,y)


binary = sorted(glob.glob('C:/Users/Desktop/bin/*.bin'))

for count,FILE in enumerate(binary):
    F = open(FILE,'rb')
    B = unpack('f'*1023183, F.read(4*1023183))
    A = np.array(B).reshape(1043, 981)
    F.close()

    #a = something column 1   # some further processing
    #b =  something column 2  # and generates 1D data


    ax2 =fig.add_subplot(212,axisbg='w')
    ax2.plot(a,b)

plt.show()
```